# How does one efficiently filter the bottom most items of a nested array and object structure while also keeping the path info to such items?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, filter

I have an array of data as follows.

An array of continents, which each has an array of regions and which each has an array of countries. E.g.

```
continents:[
  {
     Name: 'Europe',
     Regions: [
       {
         Name: Western Europe,
         Countries: [
           {
             Name: 'United Kingdom'
           },
           {
             Name: 'Republic of Ireland'
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
  }
]
```

I have a search field in which the user can search for a country.
What I need to do is to be able to filter the results to show only the search for country but also display the region and continent.

E.g. if the user searches for 'United' it would display

```
Europe
  -> Western Europe
     -> **United** Kingdom

Americas
  -> North America
     -> **United** States of America
```

Ive hit a wall. Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what output you want in a js syntax?

Comment: I mean showing the structure in a js syntax, for example what is western europe in your output ? `objects`, `arrays` etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the given data structure and the OP's task the first thing one has to do, is to (exactly once) reassemble or to [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce#how_reduce_works) the given structure into a flat list of country items where each item besides its `country` field also features the country's `region` and `continent` properties ... something like this ...

```
... ,{
  country: "Republic of Ireland",
  region: "Western Europe",
  continent: "Europe"
}, {
  country: "Indonesia",
  region: "Southeast Asia",
  continent: "Asia"
}, ...
```

The still open search/query task then can be implemented in a very straightforward way of [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)ing such a flat list of country items by e.g. looking for any item's *lowercase* name which [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) the likewise [*lowercase*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) name query ...

```
function queryCountryListByName(nameQuery) {
  return listOfCountryItems.filter(item =>
    item.country.toLowerCase().includes(nameQuery.toLowerCase())
  );
}
```

```js
function createAndCollectCountryItemWithContext(list, item) {
//const context = this; // e.g. { continent: 'Europe', region: 'Western Europe' }
  return list.concat(
    Object.assign({ country: item.Name }, this)
  );
}
function createAndCollectCountryItemFromRegionWithContext(list, item) {
//const context = this; // e.g. { continent: 'Europe' }
  return list.concat(
    item.Countries.reduce(
      createAndCollectCountryItemWithContext.bind(
        Object.assign({ region: item.Name }, this)
      ), []
    )
  );
}
function createAndCollectCountryItemFromRegionAndContinent(list, item) {
  return list.concat(
    item.Regions.reduce(
      createAndCollectCountryItemFromRegionWithContext.bind({
        continent: item.Name,
      }), []
    )
  );
}

const contriesGroupedByRegiosAndContinents = [{
  Name: 'Europe',
  Regions: [{
    Name: 'Western Europe',
    Countries: [{
      Name: 'United Kingdom',
    }, {
      Name: 'Republic of Ireland',
    }],
  }],
}, {
  Name: 'Asia',
  Regions: [{
    Name: 'Southeast Asia',
    Countries: [{
      Name: 'Indonesia',
    }, {
      Name: 'Philippines',
    }],
  }],
}, {
  Name: 'Americas',
  Regions: [{
    Name: 'North America',
    Countries: [{
      Name: 'United States of America',
    }, {
      Name: 'Canada',
    }],
  }],
}];

const listOfCountryItems = contriesGroupedByRegiosAndContinents.reduce(
  createAndCollectCountryItemFromRegionAndContinent, []
);
console.log('listOfCountryItems ...', listOfCountryItems);


function queryCountryListByName(nameQuery) {
  return listOfCountryItems.filter(item =>
    item.country.toLowerCase().includes(nameQuery.trim().toLowerCase())
  );
}

console.log(
  "queryCountryListByName('  united  ') ...",
  queryCountryListByName('  united  ')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

We could start by filtering continents using [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) (for both Regions and Countries), then looping over the matching continents to log the results:

```js
// The string to search for.
let str = "United"

continents = [
{
     Name: 'Europe',
     Regions: [
       {
         Name: 'Western Europe',
         Countries: [
           {
             Name: 'United Kingdom'
           },
           {
             Name: 'Republic of Ireland'
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
  },
  {
     Name: 'Americas',
     Regions: [
       {
         Name: 'North America',
         Countries: [
           {
             Name: 'Canada'
           },
           {
             Name: 'United States of America'
           }
         ]
       }
     ]
  }
]

// Find all continents with matching countries
let matchingContinents = continents.filter(continent => continent.Regions.some(region => region.Countries.some(country => country.Name.includes(str))));
for(let continent of matchingContinents) {
    console.log(continent.Name);
    for(let region of continent.Regions) {
        console.log(" -> " + region.Name);
        for(let country of region.Countries) {
            if (country.Name.includes(str)) {
                console.log("   -> " + country.Name.replace(str, '**' + str + '**'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Taking into account a lot of search tasks (maybe searching while typing) over a vast amount of countries, grouped by quite a lot of regions, spread over at least 5 continents, one could think of a more efficient way of filtering.

Comment: That's a good point @PeterSeliger, but we're talking about maybe two hundred countries in total. I suspect we're talking microseconds to filter that array, so it's probably not necessary to optimize for speed..

Comment: That's totally correct for the OP's current task here and now ... but ... for bigger and long living applications / software etc.,  if one applies this way of thinking to every more complex task which needs to be solved, one will end up over the years with slower and harder to read/maintain code.

Comment: I agree with you, it just depends on context!

Comment: btw ... this kind of comments/talk is not meant for teaching you. I want to reach the beginners. I would like them to think about approaches and their implications. Thanks for taking it so egoless. One does not find it that often at SO.

Comment: Totally agree again @PeterSeliger, we're all here to learn. I will not take offense at code critiques, that is essential. I think as programmers we must all learn to take advice on best practice!

Answer (score -1):

So from what I understand, you want to take your big array of objects and return a filtered version with the same structure? If so, you could do it like this.

```js
const continents = [{
  Name: 'Europe',
  Regions: [{
    Name: 'Western Europe',
    Countries: [{
      Name: 'United Kingdom',
    }, {
      Name: 'Republic of Ireland',
    }],
  }],
}, {
  Name: 'Asia',
  Regions: [{
    Name: 'Southeast Asia',
    Countries: [{
      Name: 'Indonesia',
    }, {
      Name: 'Philippines',
    }],
  }],
}, {
  Name: 'Americas',
  Regions: [{
    Name: 'North America',
    Countries: [{
      Name: 'United States of America',
    }, {
      Name: 'Canada',
    }],
  }],
}];

const result = continents.map(con => {
  if(con.Regions.some(reg => reg.Countries.some(c => c.Name.startsWith('United')))){

    return {
      ...con,
      Regions: con.Regions.map(reg => {
        if(reg.Countries.some(c => c.Name.startsWith('United'))){
          return {
            ...reg,
            Countries: reg.Countries.filter(c => c.Name.startsWith('United'))
          }
        }
      }) 
    }
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Obviously you would want to replace `'United'` with whatever your search term is.